# How to code efficient background image

Tags: java, swing

please I am coding a 2D game with java,but my background image does not load up with the JFrame it loads up when I drag the JFrame, since it resizeable

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 public class imageLearn1 extends JFrame{
  private Image im;
  private JPanel p1;

  public imageLearn1(){
   this.setSize(300,400);
   this.setVisible(true);
   this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   p1=new paintIt();
   this.add(p1);
   }
   class paintIt extends JPanel{
         public paintIt(){
       ImageIcon ima=new ImageIcon("ballfall3.jpg");
       im=ima.getImage();

      im=im.getScaledInstance(200,-1,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
      }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(im!=null){
          g.drawImage(im,0,0,300,400,this);
        }
      }
   }


     public static void main(String[]args){
           new imageLearn1();

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the components to the frame before making the frame visible. The order of the code should be:

```
p1=new paintIt();
this.add(p1);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setSize(300,400);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Also, class names should start with an upper case character. You class name should be "PaintIt".